# Renting a vehicle and grand theft auto

Tags: united-states, theft, rent, vehicle, car

Let's say hypothetically someone rents a vehicle to another person. They sign a contract and the other individual agrees to pay $300 to the person at the start of every month. The contract also states that if they are two months late on rent the car will be reported stolen. Both parties sign this contract.

Now let's say the individual does not pay after 2 months. Can the car be reported as stolen to the authorities?

If the police find the car and the individual would the individual be charged with grand theft auto? Or would the police be angry at the person reporting the crime because they had a contract to rent the car the other individual was just not paying?

Let's say hypothetically this is in the United States and New Jersey

Comment: Rental companies routinely do this. Sometimes the bureaucracy gets it wrong. https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2022/dec/17/hertz-car-rental-accused-customers-auto-theft

Comment: Needs a country tag.

Comment: The problem with this question/contract is that it does not specify what remedy is available to the renter if they can***not*** pay.  There has to be some remedy, in the contract or in law for the possibility of financial incapacity that is not a criminal offense.  Presumably they should be able to just return the vehicle, but this is not stated.

Comment: I think this is exactly why repo professionals exist.  I'm also a little dubious that such a contract is legal/meaningful in most places i.e.: the part about 'reporting it stolen'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

In Colorado, the relevant statute states:

> (1) A person commits theft when he or she knowingly . . . retains,
> or exercises control over anything of value of another without
> authorization . . . and: . . .
>
> (e) **Knowingly retains the thing of value more than seventy-two hours
> after the agreed-upon time of return in any lease or hire
> agreement**[.]

Colo. Rev. Stat. Ann. § 18-4-401.

The law in this fact pattern is not entirely uniform across the United States, so other states may have a criminal statute that leads to a different outcome.

Comment: This is not a direct match to OP's scenario. The person renting the car didn't necessarily miss a "time of return". Say the contract was to rent the car for 6 months and there was no provision to shorten this (i.e., no right to return the car early and stop paying). Then after not paying for 2 months, the renter has failed to meet their financial obligation, but this doesn't necessarily make the car stolen. Early return of the car might be sought as a civil remedy (much as one can evict a non-paying residential tenant partway through a lease), but that would be via lawsuit rather than police.

Comment: Also, you didn't directly address the question "would the police be angry at the person reporting the crime because...the other individual was just not paying?" Of course "angry" is not well-defined legally, but I interpret it as "would it be considered a false report?" Here I think it's important to note that reports to police from the public are about *facts* and are not treated as legal judgments. So if the car owner uses the word "stolen" with police, the reporting issue is not whether the scenario fits the local theft statue, but whether the material circumstances are stated truthfully.

Comment: @nanoman The question states "The contract also states that if they are two months late on rent the car will be reported stolen." It is reasonable to infer that this implies that the lease includes an obligation to return the car prior to that date. I interpret the language about "would the police be angry" (which indeed doesn't have a well-defined legal meaning) to refer to whether the owner was justified in reporting  the car as stolen under the applicable law.

Comment: @ohwilleke I think the OP intended that as something like "Are the police likely to act on this report, or would they to tell the reporter to deal with this through civil litigation?" Since it's basically just a breach of contract.

Comment: @Barmar: Except it's *not* "just" a breach of contract. ohwilleke has cited a criminal statute prohibiting the conduct in question, so it is a criminal offense (at least in Colorado, anyway). Whether the local police are willing to enforce criminal statutes is, of course, not a legal question.

Comment: @Kevin I wonder if this is simply an invalid contract term. When you get a car loan and default on the loan, they don't report you to the police, they repossess the car. If it were possible to get the police to intervene instead of paying a repo man, I'm sure they would.

Comment: @Barmar Most repos are for owned rather than leased cars where there is a default on the car loan. I suspect that the intent of the criminal provision in Colorado was people who rent cars on a short term basis with an intent never to return them, but by its terms it applies to long term car leases as well.

Comment: I admit that I haven't read the fine print of a car loan, but if they can repossess it suggests that the contract gives them ownership if you default (otherwise reposessing is stealing from the car owner). And if it gives the bank ownership, they could report it as theft.

Comment: @Barmar In a traditional car loan, it is only a crime if you actively conceal the car that is in default from the lender, since the lender doesn't own it until the UCC foreclosure process has run its course.

Comment: @Barmar In a car or home loan, the lender doesn't have ownership, they have a _lien_ on the property. There are specific procedures to exercise their rights under the lien, that is foreclosure.

Comment: @user71659 I guess I'm wondering why loans are done that way, rather than more like the OP's scenario, where the lender gets ownership and then they can report it stolen? This makes me think there's some reason why that contract structure isn't legal. OTOH, I guess that's how a lease-to-own works -- the lessee doesn't get ownership until they pay the full amount.

Comment: @Barmar It preserves the car/homeowner's rights. The bank can't one day say "as 80% owner, I want to sell the house now and take a profit" and you get stuck without a place to live. It also avoids liability for accidents or the bank having to maintain the house as expected from an owner. In a lease, the owner is the finance company. Also, Jewish/Islamic loans are structured as a partial ownership to avoid religious prohibitions on interest.

Comment: @user71659 So the OP's scenario is more like a lease than a loan.

Comment: @Barmar The question says "Let's say hypothetically someone rents a vehicle to another person." It is specifically about a lease and not a loan.

Comment: "I guess I'm wondering why loans are done that way, rather than more like the OP's scenario," The ownership and loan scenario is the norm. Leasing is mostly driven by tax considerations. You can deduct 100% of a lease payment on a car claimed for business use. The match between payments and deductions with cars used for business use is different when you own - principal can't be deducted but you get depreciation instead over a number of years. It also suits someone who wants to replace one newer car with another every few years. For personal use cars you can't deduct the costs either way.